# How to validate mobile Number using data annotation in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I need to validate all the Indian mobile number using data annotation. in my model i use following code

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    [CustomRemote("IsMobileNoAvailable", "Employees",
     ErrorMessage = "Mobile No already in use", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
    [?]

    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
```

but i am confuse what i need to write in place of [?] ? Please suggest me the best way to validate mobile number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one hope it will help you.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([0]|\+91[\-\s]?)?[789]\d{9}$", ErrorMessage = "Entered Mobile No is not valid.")]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add this regex in place of [?]

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
```